# Why 3D models are not showing in 2D?

Tags: anylogic

I am new to AnyLogic and I've been trying out some learning resource from **AnyLogic in 3 Days**.

I am currently trying out **Discrete Events** which I am asked to use 3D models. I look at the figures in the PDF and it shows the models in the Agents tab when zooming to 500% and in the 2D simulation. In my Agent's tab zooming to 500% Display nothing, but yes you can click on the 0, 0 Coordinate and it displays a bounding box.

In the simulation Window, the simulation runs like a ghost with no models also showing up, but in the 3D model, the models show up and animate without a problem.

In the model properties, the **Advance** section **shows in**, **2D and 3D** is already selected.

Can anyone tell me if there is any configuration to be done to AnyLogic?

Currently, I am using **AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition 8.6.0**, running on **Windows 7 Service Pack 1**.
My notebook is running with **Intel I-Core7 @2.8GHz**, **16GB of RAM**, and **Nvidia Quadro M1000 (2GB VRAM)**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Some of the Screenshots:

[3d Image not showing in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZdij.png)

[Orientation in Properties also shows nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oblfO.png)

[In the simulation window, 3D object not showing in 2D, but in the 3D are showing in 3D Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exir7.png)

Comment: any screenshots would be appreciated ;). And welcome to SOF and AnyLogic :)

Comment: @Benjamin: I've already added some screenshots. any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did yo uaccidentally delete the 3D files in the model subfolder "3D models"? Looks very weird

Comment: No. the *.dae file is still there. It showing up in 3D Windows well

Comment: Any problems with the default example models? If yes, check with AL support as this would be weird. If no, you did something wrong. Try to replicate your steps from a default example model and see what causes the 3D models to disappear :)

Comment: The example also shows the same symptom. I'll try to contact the AnyLogic support. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I made a copy of the model and saved it to a new folder on my computer. Thereafter, I deleted the DAE file under the 3D file in my new copied model folder. Then went back into Anylogic and deleted the 3D objects of my agents and placed new 3D objects into my agents that had that problem. You can find all 3D objects in Anylogic at the last block under Palette.

In other words, delete the old DAE files that broke your 3D objects in your model file location on your computer and add new 3D objects into your agents in Anylogic.

It worked for me.